# Java MDB multiple destination propertyValue( mdb configuration)

Tags: java, jboss, message, jboss-mdb

I have MDB files which can be fired from multiple JMS channels. How I can achieve this? For one channel it works perfectly:

```
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "jms/mirkuponov/emailSystemEventTopic")
```

But when I try to add multiple `@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination"`
it doesn't listen for 1-st destination and works only for 2nd.